# HTTP Location Header Rewrite - moving logic from IIS proxy to IBM datapower

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0, pcre, ibm-datapower

We are moving Location Header Rewrite logic from IIS reverse proxy to IBM dataPower XI52.. I know we have header rewrite functionality on DP but I am not able to understand how we can implement below scenario on DP, can you please guide me? May I know what is R:1, R:2 and R:3 are referring here?
Location HeaderRewrite outgoing rule on IIS reverse proxy:

```
<rule name="Change Location Header" enabled="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301" />
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^302" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://{R:2}/{R:3}" />
            </rule>
```

May I know how we can implement the same on DP ?

I tried using below xslt, but getting empty LocationHeader_output value, am doing something wrong here ?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
xmlns:re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
extension-element-prefixes="dp re"
exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="dp:responding()">
            <xsl:variable name="code">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="dp:http-response-header('x-dp-response-code') != ''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(dp:http-response-header('x-dp-response-code'), 1, 3)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(dp:variable('var://service/error-headers'), 10, 3)" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$code = '301' or $code = '302'">
                <xsl:variable name="location" select="dp:http-response-header('Location')"/>

                <xsl:variable name="location_final">
                    <xsl:value-of select="re:replace($location, '^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)', 'g', 'http{$1}://{$2}/{$3}')" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <dp:set-http-response-header name="'Location'" value="$location_final" />
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- the following prevent DataPower from overriding the response code coming back from Server-->
            <dp:set-response-header name="'x-dp-response-code'" value="'-1'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using below xslt in IBM DataPower

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
xmlns:re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
extension-element-prefixes="dp re"
exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="code">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="dp:http-response-header('x-dp-response-code') != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(dp:http-response-header('x-dp-response-code'), 1, 3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(dp:variable('var://service/error-headers'), 10, 3)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="info">
  HTTP response Code:<xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
    </xsl:message>
    <xsl:if test="$code = '301' or $code = '302'">
        <xsl:variable name="location" select="dp:http-response-header('Location')"/>

        <xsl:variable name="location_final">
            <xsl:value-of select="re:replace($location, '^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)', 'g', 'http$1://$2/$3')" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <dp:set-http-response-header name="'Location'" value="$location_final" />
        <xsl:message dp:priority="info">
  Response Location_beforeModify:<xsl:value-of select="$location"/>
  Response Location_AfterModify:<xsl:value-of select="$location_final"/>
<!--   Response test Regex:<xsl:value-of select="re:replace('https://demo.cloudimg.io/s/width/300/sample.li/boat.jpg', '^http(s)?://([^/]+)/(.*)', 'g', 'http$1://$2/$3')" />   -->
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- the following prevent DataPower from overriding the response code coming back from Server-->
    <dp:set-response-header name="'x-dp-response-code'" value="'-1'"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works well for me.

```
<xsl:variable name="locationHeader" select="dp:http-response-header('Location')"/>
<xsl:if test="starts-with($locationHeader, 'http://') or starts-with($locationHeader, 'https://')">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(dp:variable('var://service/URL-in'), 'https')">
      <dp:set-http-response-header name="'Location'" value="concat('https://', dp:variable('var://service/local-service-address'), '/', substring-after(substring-after($locationHeader, '://'), '/'))"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(dp:variable('var://service/URL-in'), 'http')">
      <dp:set-http-response-header name="'Location'" value="concat('http://', dp:variable('var://service/local-service-address'), '/', substring-after(substring-after($locationHeader, '://'), '/'))"/>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```